# Branching my repo in Github

Tags: git, version-control, github

I'm using the OS X github app with Git/Github, although I do occasionly go to the command line for more intrepid things.

I have a repo "serge-denimes-theme" which is used for production as well as small incremental updates. I simply work on my local version and commit/push for an update. There is only one (master) branch.

I want to make a major update to the repo but retain the current branch all the while for incremental updates. I figure the best way is to make a branch and work on that separately from the master branch. When the major update is ready I can merge it back to the master.

How would I go about making this branch and getting a local copy of it that I can work on and commit/push to without influencing the master branch?

Edit: The idea being I have both the master branch and the feature branch on my local environment separate from each other so I can work on them both independantly

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for the 'github app', but as you do have a command line, this is the general idea:

> `git checkout -b mybranch #branch 'mybranch' off the current branch, switch to it`
>   `#hack hack hack; commit changes`
>   `git checkout master #switch back to master branch`
>   `git merge mybranch #merge mybranch into master`